# SQLiteを使って構築した SNS でフォローしている人だけの投稿を表示したい

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

SQLite(+PHP)でSNSを作っています。現状、テーブル定義は以下のようになっています。

フォローの情報を入れている`follow`に、フォロー元のユーザーIDである`from_id`と、フォロー先のユーザーIDである`to_id`が存在しています。また、投稿テーブルとして、`post`があり、投稿ユーザーIDとして`user_id`があります。

このようなテーブルが定義されているときに、フォローしている人だけの投稿を取得し、表示するにはどうすればいいかがわかりません。どうすればいいのでしょうか?

Comment: 申し訳ありません。
select * from post where (user_id=(select to_id from follow where from_id=自分のID) or user_id=自分のID
で解決しました。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ!良ければ、[自分で回答して下さい](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!

Comment: と思ったら、最後にフォローした人しか見れませんでした。

Comment: テーブルの `.scheme` などがあると質問の見通しがよくなりそうです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下の SQL で取得可能です。

```
SELECT * 
FROM   post 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   follow 
               WHERE  follow.to_id = post.user_id 
                      AND follow.from_id = 自分のid)
```

コメントにお書きになられている方法だと「フォローしているうちの誰か１人の投稿」となる気がします。

Answer (score 0):

ということはこういう感じですかね。

SELECT <投稿そのもの> FROM folloe F
INNER JOIN post P ON P.user_id=from_id
WHERE to_id=<フォロー先のID>

こうなれば、～をフォローしている人の発言を出せるはずです。
質問内にはpostテーブルの構造が少ないため、発言そのものの列がわからないのでこのように書いていますが。

あとは、このクエリをPHPでアウトプットすればよいと思いますが。